# The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it. (NSData dataWithContentsOfFile)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, file-permissions, nsimage

I'm trying to use Core Media IO to create a virtual camera/fake webcam and feed an image into it in the plugin itself. I started with the DAL minimal example (https://github.com/johnboiles/coremediaio-dal-minimal-example/blob/master/CMIOMinimalSample/Stream.mm) and am changing the createPixelBufferWithTestAnimation function. I'm trying to create an NSImage with the constructor initWithContentsOfURL, but the NSImage is always null.

I used NSData to find the error, which says 'The file “current.png” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.' However, the permissions of the image are read-write all around. I also moved the image into the project folder as a resource, but I keep getting this error.

[A picture of the logs in Console.app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEif9.png)

Comment: Is your app sandboxed? (I believe the default app template will enable sandboxing). Try turning it off (edit the `.entitlements` file).

Comment: @NSGod I don't think so, there's no .entitlements file.  There's not even a sandboxing option in Signing and capabilities, I think because it's not an app, it's a plugin,